# PHP Multiple Drop Down Variables Empty

Tags: php, variables, drop-down-menu

I am performing some validation on three different drop down menus. If all three variables are NULL, I am wanting to direct the user to the specific error. I am asking the visitor to choose one of the dropdowns, not all three. Here is my line of code that I cant see to get working:

```
if ( $dropdown1 == 'NULL', $dropdown2 == 'NULL', $dropdown3 == 'NULL' ) {
echo '<h1>Error Edited For the Sake of Brevity</h1>';
}
else
```

Apreciate any thoughts anyone could share with me.
Thanks Again,
--Matt

Comment: I have yet to see comma operator being used in structure controls the way you have used it.

Comment: what is the datatype of $dropdown? is it a string or is it not set?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're probably getting all of the values from $_REQUEST/$_GET/$_POST (I'm using $_REQUEST below because it works for all), for that you'd use [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php).

```
if( !isset( $_REQUEST[ 'dropdown1' ] ) && 
    !isset( $_REQUEST[ 'dropdown2' ] ) && 
    !isset( $_REQUEST[ 'dropdown3' ] ) ) 
{
    // none of them are set.
}
```

If you're actually looking to see if the variables themselves are set to null, then you should use [is_null](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php)

```
if( is_null( $dropdown1 ) && 
    is_null( $dropdown2 ) && 
    is_null( $dropdown3 ) )
{
    // none of them are set.
}
```

Finally, if you have reason to believe that they will be the STRING value `'NULL'` then you can use `==` (this is a comparably rare circumstance):

```
if( 'NULL' == $dropdown1 && 
    'NULL' == $dropdown2 && 
    'NULL' == $dropdown3 )
{
    // none of them are set.
}
```

You can change any of the above to test to see if any of them are not set by using || (or) instead of && (and):

```
if( 'NULL' == $dropdown1 || 
    'NULL' == $dropdown2 || 
    'NULL' == $dropdown3 )
{
    // one of them is not set.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're trying to do a boolean AND comparison, which in PHP is:

```
if ( $dropdown1 == 'NULL' && $dropdown2 == 'NULL' && $dropdown3 == 'NULL' )...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( $dropdown1 == 'NULL', $dropdown2 == 'NULL', $dropdown3 == 'NULL' ) {
```

should be

```
if ( $dropdown1 == 'NULL' || $dropdown2 == 'NULL' || $dropdown3 == 'NULL' ) {
```

In this case if any of the variables is null, the it will display your error message

Comment: Just wanted to point out that he's trying to do an AND operation, not OR.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using commas to separate the conditions

```
if ( $dropdown1 == 'NULL' || $dropdown2 == 'NULL' || $dropdown3 == 'NULL' )
```

Comment: I don't know why I bothered posting this, I should have known there would be 5 other answers by the time I finished typing!

Comment: Just wanted to point out that he's trying to do an AND operation, not OR.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to give error message when all of the dropdowns are null then you should use this condition

if($dropdown1 == 'NULL' && $dropdown2 == 'NULL' && $dropdown3 == 'NULL' ){

echo $error_msg;
}